# Conceder permisos a carpeta IIS

Tags: php, mysql, iis, windows-server-2012

Tengo un script en que debe desplegar imagenes de la base de datos, pero me muestra el error 0X80070005 cannot read configuration file due to insufficent permissions:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si tienes usuario root, puedes darle permisos a la carpeta, o al propio archivo, con **chmod**

Comment: Dale permisos de lectura y escritura al directorio "images" para los usuarios "IUSR" y "IIS_IUSRS"

Comment: @OmarViñas ya lo hice y nada

Comment: El archivo y/o carpeta existe es común que de el error si no existe la carpeta